# Calling Command Prompt from Rational Clearquest doesnt work

Tags: clearquest

By using Rational Clearquest Eclipse Designer I have created hook under which

I have below code,

```
system(java -jar <Jar file> <Excelfilepath> <Excelpathwheretostore>
```

My question this works fine in Windows Clearquest Client not in Webclient.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Is this supposed to start a Java application that the user is supposed to interact with? The hook is run on the same system as the CQ Web server, not the web browser. It won't be very useful in that scenario because the user is on a different system.

If this is just a command line java program, then then possible reasons are:

1) The web server runs as localsystem, and can't access the resources that the user can access when running from the Windows client.

or

2) The paths to java or to the jars are not correct.